# What Hanzi-Latin hybrid characters exist?

Tags: characters

I was going through Babel Stone's [PUA](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/PUA.html) page when I came across, some, of the following characters. This one is Japanese:

> [image]
>   Kanji-Latin hybrid = 慶 in the name of Keiō University (慶應大学)

This one is Korean:

> [image]
>   Hanja-Hangul hybrid = 圖 do "map" ([Evidence](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/CJK/Evidence/Korea_Road_Atlas.jpg))

This one is Zhuang:

> [image]
>   Sawndip-Latin hybrid = enj "to stick out one's chest or stomach" (= ⿰益先 in Ext. G)

So, we've got Kanji-Latin hybrid, Hanja-Hangul hybrid & Sawndip-Latin hybrid characters, but where are the Hanzi-Latin hybrid characters?

What Hanzi-Latin hybrid characters exist? (If any?)

Answer (score 7):

If you consider only "official" characters encoded in the Unicode 12.1, as opposed to the Private Use Area (PUA) that you are referring to, or other unstandardized and humorous characters, then there doesn't seem to be any Latin-Hanzi hybrids. **At all.**

I carefully looked through Unicode 12.1 ranges for Chinese, Japanese, Korean, and Vietnamese characters, specifically:

- [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3400.pdf)
- [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20000.pdf) – this document alone took me 3 days to process.
- [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2A700.pdf)
- [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2B740.pdf)
- [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2B820.pdf)
- [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2CEB0.pdf)
- [CJK Compatibility Ideographs](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UF900.pdf)
- [CJK Unified Ideographs](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U4E00.pdf)

And noticed plenty of unusual and peculiar ideographs, like these:

[image: Unusual Chinese characters]
[image: Strange Chinese and Japanese hieroglyphs]
[image: Peculiar Chinese and Japanese characters]

But not a single character contains a Latin letter.

The closest to look like having a letter inside are these two. They have a stroke that looks precisely like a lowercase Greek [alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha):

[image: A radical looks like Greek alpha letter]

Comment: That's quite some dedication, and extremely interesting.

Comment: @MiCl, I was just curious what are the strangest characters I could possibly find. As well as whether there are indeed any Hanzi-Latin hybrids.

Comment: More strange characters: [Are there no rounded or circular strokes in any 漢字？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65664/32610)

Comment:  looks like it says "ok" when it's written small.

Comment: For your information, Ken Lunde recently [(january 2020)](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2020/20059-unihan-kstrange-update.pdf) proposed to add a property `kStrange` in unicode to track these curiois han characters. The linked proposal condtains a list, and in the characters already encoded in Unicde, two from extendsion F might qualify as latin hybrid: U+2CF01  (from U+0292 ʒ LATIN SMALL LETTER EZH, symbol for “dram,” and U+2CF04  (from U+2125 ℥ OUNCE SIGN), both of japanese origin

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans, that's a very interesting character compilation indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to eliminate all possibilities. But from daily life, there is no such hybrid characters. It is more simple to treat a Latin letter as a character. There is no practical use of it.

For example, 維他命Ａ (Vitamin A, also known as 維生素甲)，Ｔ尺 (T-square, also known as 丁字尺)，Ｔ恤(T-shirt, also known as 短袖圓領衫).

In Hong Kong, it is common to write Arabic numerals and Latin letters for shorthand in work or less formal conversation, mixing homophone and shape and English. For example, 0T for 檸茶(lemon tea), 0水 for 檸水(lemon water), c9 for 師奶 (housewives).

You might find hybrid in the brand logos and some artistic designs.

There is a joke in a Hong Kong film Love Undercover (新紮師妹) and create a fake hybrid character like this.

[image: Sir as surname]

Answer (score 0):

1. Hanzi-Latin hybrid characters should be a system using Hanzi and Latin characters simultaneously
2. Hanzi strobes and Latin charaters definitely can not be mingled in ONE symbol. I never heard that. However Hanzi characters and Latin charaters can occur sequentially in a sentence and a paragraph